# When executing DidSelectRowAt, variables no longer have their values

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, data-transfer, didselectrowatindexpath

I am currently working on one project, but I have encountered this problem. When executing didSelectRowAt, variables that are not being assigned within initializing are being deleted.
Basically, I need to get value of what row did I select previously if I did. I have done this project to simplify the problem. I have two ViewControllers and when I click on any of the rows from tableView at the first ViewController, it switches to the second ViewController. There the value is changing in the original project. When coming back to the first ViewController I need to compare this indexValue with the row I click. Any advice will be appreciated. :)

The First ViewController

```
var globalIndex: Int!
var delegate: passDataDelegate!
let valueForExample = "This is just to show, how program behaves."

func passData(index: Int?) {
    globalIndex = index
    //When printing globalIndex, it shows normal value
}

let array = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableView", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("Global index is \(globalIndex)")
    //When printing globalIndex, the value is always nil, however when I print valueForExample it normally shows its value
    if(globalIndex == indexPath.row) {
        print("You pressed the same button as before")
    }
    let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondViewController
    delegate = secondVC
    delegate.passData(index: indexPath.row)
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(secondVC, animated: true)
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialConfiguration()

}

func initialConfiguration() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customTableView")
}
```

Second ViewController

```swift
protocol delegate {
    func passData(index: Int?)
}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, passDataDelegate {

    var globalIndex: Int!
    var delegat: delegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let firstVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC") as! ViewController
        delegat = firstVC
        delegat.passData(index: globalIndex)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func passData(index: Int) {
        globalIndex = index
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to pass the index value from first ViewController to second ViewController, Then on dismiss of second ViewController, what you need to check ? Can you explain

Comment: In the original project, I pass to the second ViewController index, which I use in array to get musicURL to play the music. You can also switch between next/previous song (index changes). When going back to the first ViewController where I have table view of songs that you want to play, I want it to know what song is playing (according to index from second ViewController) so that when I click on the name of music that is already playing, It won't start redownloading it and will simply continue playing.

Comment: You can refer this GitHub project which I have created [link](https://github.com/CatherinKG/Song-Studio.git) Do refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In First ViewController**

```
var globalIndex: Int? //Make global index optional

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("Global index is \(globalIndex)")

    if(globalIndex == indexPath.row) {
        print("You pressed the same button as before")
    }

    let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondViewController
    secondVC.delegat = self // Set delegate
    secondVC.globalIndex = indexPath.row //Set global index
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(secondVC, animated: true)
}

extension FirstViewController: passDelegate {
    func passData(index: Int?){
        globalIndex = index // Set index from second view controller to first viewcontroller
    }
}
```

**In Second ViewController**

```
protocol passDelegate {
    func passData(index: Int?)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
   var globalIndex: Int!
   var delegat: delegate!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
       delegat.passData(index: globalIndex) //Call delegate
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but It didn't work. :/ But thanks for your advice! :) When I looked at the app, I apply the same principle, but now, it doesnt work.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Yesterday, I found out that when I don't use dismiss on the second ViewController, It works, however I am not sure wether it's ideal to use present instead of dismiss because it could be wasting RAM so I try to find some workaround. Basically, I just need to know what row did I select previously when clicking on the tableView.

Comment: I made a GitHub repository as I made a little change to make it more clean.
Here is a link: https://github.com/JosefZetek/Stack-Overflow-usingDelegates/blob/master/Passing%20data/ViewController.swift
And I would like to thank you a lot! 

Comment: @pepa-zetek See this https://github.com/CatherinKG/Stack-Overflow-usingDelegates.git